# rotation around point xna 2D

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to rotate one object (box texture) around another object (a semi-circle texture). I'm not sure where to start if anyone could help me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx